# How to change Visual studio code active code window title color?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to change Visual studio code active code window title color?

[image]

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference#_editor-groups-tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
       "tab.activeBackground": "#6bdc6b",
}
```